# Automation to find EC2 instance with a public IP address

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Goal: automation to find an ec2 instance information (aws ec2 describe-instances) in any project/region of an organization by public IP address (should be at most one because public IPs are unique).

Requirements: IAM user on management account for the organization that has an AssumeRole with the correct permissions for all accounts in the organization. The RoleName will have to be specified by user and be the same for all accounts.

Plan:

- Find all accounts in the organization with `aws organizations` commands (list-roots, list-children).
- AssumeRole for these accounts one by one using provided RoleName.
  -- Once role is assumed, determine all applicable regions in the account with `aws ec2 describe-regions`.
  -- Iterate over all available regions to determine if an ec2 instance with the public IP exists: `aws ec2 describe-instance --filter=“Name=ipaddress,Value=<ip>” --region <region>`.
  -- This should be one and done so once found, quit.
  -- If no instances found, return “not found message”.

Does this logic make sense and/or is there a better way to do it?  Seems like it would work but LOTS of API calls and seems like there should be a better way.  Thanks in advance for your help!

I have started to create this script using python3/boto3 but it seems like there should be a better way

Comment: AWS Config might give you this out of the box. Alternatively, AWS Systems Manager might give you a way to automate the search.

Comment: so no really free and easy ways?

Answer (score 0):

A few useful resources:

- [Collecting AWS networking information in large multi-account environments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/collecting-aws-networking-information-in-large-multi-account-environments/)
- [Find Public IPs of Resources – Use AWS Config for Vulnerability Assessment](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/find-public-ips-of-resources-use-aws-config-for-vulnerability-assessment/)
- [IPAM View IP address history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/ipam/view-history-cidr-ipam.html)

Comment: Thanks, IPAM seems the most straight forward for just IP addresses but still kind of a bummer that there were be additional configuration and cost.  Other CSPs can pull but information on IP addresses globally in single API calls so that is what I was looking for.

I was pretty much working on a version of this automation: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-sts-network-query-tool/
However, for large organizations it still takes long periods of time to run (30 minutes or more) so not optimal.